# insert typname into template function name

Tags: c++, templates

Is it in any way possible to put the typename parameter of a template into a function name.
For example:

```
template<typename T>
class MyTemplate {
public:
  void my[T]Something();
};

MyTemplate<MyThingy> something;
somethng.myMyThingySomething();
```

Answer (score 2):

Template specialization should solve this issue for you.

Just replace `myMyThingySomething()` with `mySomething<MyThingy>()` and explicitly define the specialization of `mySomething` for the type `MyThingy`.

Comment: Tried this and I get these compiler errors:
error expedted ';' at end of member declaration
error variable or field 'mySomething' declared void
error expectied unqualified-id before '<' token

Comment: without seeing your code it is hard to determine what the problem os.  please refer to this page for information on how template specialization works: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization